# Proof of Vector Triple Product by Directions and Magnitudes

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, cross-product

I'm trying to prove the vector triple product expansion by magnitude and direction:
$$ \vec{a} \times(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})=(\vec a\cdot \vec{c})\vec{b} - (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})\vec{c} $$
The equality of direction is easy: using the property of the cross product that $\vec{b} \times \vec{c} $ is orthogonal to both $ \vec{b} $ and $\vec{c} $.
But I can't give a correct proof for the latter. Where is my error? My trying is following:

Let $ \theta $ be the angle between $ \vec{a} $ and the plane containing $ \vec{b} $ and $ \vec{c} $, $ \varphi $ be the angle between $ \vec{b} $ and $ \vec{c} $ in the plane containing them.

The left hand:

$$
\begin{align}
\Vert \vec{a} \times(\vec{b}\times \vec{c}) \Vert
&= \Vert \vec{a} \Vert  \Vert \vec{b}\times \vec{c} \Vert \vert\sin \theta \vert 
\\&= \Vert \vec{a} \Vert  \Vert \vec{b} \Vert \Vert \vec{c} \Vert \vert\sin \theta \vert \vert\sin\varphi \vert
\end{align}
$$

The right hand:

$$
\begin{align}
\Vert(\vec a\cdot \vec{c})\vec{b} - (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})\vec{c}\Vert ^2
& = \Vert(\vec a\cdot \vec{c})\vec{b}\Vert^2 -2 (\vec a\cdot \vec{c})(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})(\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c})+ \Vert(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})\vec{c}\Vert ^2 
\\&= 2\Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 \cos^2 (\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta) - 2\Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 \cos^2 (\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)\cos\varphi
\\ &= 2\Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 \vert\sin^2 \theta \vert  (1-\cos\varphi )
\end{align}
$$
[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEM2g.png)

Comment: No. The recommended question uses different approach.

Comment: One answer uses "Comparing the magnitude of the vectors", which you want, and  the answer by user10354138 uses $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ like you requested.

Comment: I'd recognized "Comparing the magnitude of the vectors" in the recommended question, but what I want to know is why two magnitues in my question are unequal. I can't get the reason from the recommended.

Comment: `The right hand` You seem to assume the angles between $\vec a, \vec c$ and $\vec a, \vec b$ are both $\pi/2 - \theta$. They are not.

Comment: @dxiv I see. I just wrote graph and understood for your help. For example, moving only $ \vec{c} $ changes only the angle between $ \vec{a} $ and $ \vec{c} $.

Comment: By the way how can I close this question? (I'll delete this comment after I close this question. )

Comment: @yunoa7 You can [delete your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) as long as no one answered it, or you can [post a self-answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @dxiv Okay, I'll post a self-answer after I think a little more.

Answer (score 0):

[self answer]

Let point $A(\vec{a}), B(\vec{b}), C(\vec{c}), D(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})$,

then $\angle $ AOD is $\theta $ and $\angle $ BOC is $\varphi$.
Using law of cosines,

- $
  \cos \angle AOB = \frac{\Vert\vec{a}\Vert^2 + \Vert\vec{b}\Vert^2 - \Vert\vec{a} - \vec{b} \Vert^2 }{2 \Vert\vec{a}\Vert \Vert\vec{b}\Vert}
  = \frac{  (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) }{ \Vert\vec{a}\Vert \Vert\vec{b}\Vert}
  $
- $\cos \angle AOC = \frac{  (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}) }{ \Vert\vec{a}\Vert \Vert\vec{c}\Vert}
  $

The left hand:

$$
\Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2\vert \sin\theta \sin \varphi \vert =\Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 \vert \sin\angle AOD \vert^2 \vert\sin\angle BOC \vert^2
$$

The right hand:

$$
\begin{align}\Vert(\vec a\cdot \vec{c})\vec{b} - (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})\vec{c}\Vert ^2 
&= \Vert(\vec a\cdot \vec{c})\vec{b}\Vert^2 -2 (\vec a\cdot \vec{c})(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})(\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c})+ \Vert(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b})\vec{c}\Vert ^2 
\\ &= \Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 \cos^2 \angle AOC - 2\Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 \cos \angle AOB \cos \angle AOC  \\& + \Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 \cos^2 \angle AOB 
\\ &=\Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 \frac{ \vert(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c})\vert^2}{ \Vert\vec{a}\Vert^2 \Vert\vec{c}\Vert ^2}
- 2\Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 \vert \frac{  (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) }{ \Vert\vec{a}\Vert \Vert\vec{b}\Vert}
\frac{  (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}) }{ \Vert\vec{a}\Vert \Vert\vec{c}\Vert} + \Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 \vert \frac{  \vert(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) \vert^2}{ \Vert\vec{a}\Vert ^2\Vert\vec{b}\Vert^2}
\\ &=\Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 ( \cos^2 \angle AOC - 2\cos \angle AOB \cos \angle AOC + \cos^2 \angle AOB )
\\ &=\Vert \vec{a} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{b} \Vert ^2 \Vert \vec{c} \Vert ^2 ( \cos \angle AOC - \cos \angle AOB )^2
\end{align} $$

So, if the following is correct, the proof is copmleted:
$$
\vert \sin\angle AOD \sin\angle BOC \vert=\vert \cos \angle AOC - \cos \angle AOB \vert
$$
I'll ask another question about this. (I'll add its link in this article later. )